# Null value in BasicEditField on Blackberry Device

Tags: blackberry

On testing my application in Simulator, my app runs perfectly. But on the real device i get **Null** for BasicEditField, so I'm not able to execute my application. Following is my code snippet.

```
public class Login extends MainScreen {

    private UiApplication application = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
    private BasicEditField _email = null;
    private PasswordEditField _pwd = null;
    private ButtonField login = null;
    String imei = GPRSInfo.imeiToString(GPRSInfo.getIMEI(), false);

    public Login(){

        try {
            _email = new BasicEditField("Email: ", "", 100, EditField.NO_NEWLINE);
            _email.setFont(font);
            add(_email);

            _pwd = new PasswordEditField("Password: ", "", 100, EditField.NO_NEWLINE);
            _pwd.setFont(font);
            add(_pwd);

            login = new ButtonField("Login", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
            login.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                    String e = _email.getText();
                    String xmlUrl = "http://********:9090/com.infra.rest/rest/todo?email='"+ e +"'&dId='"+ imei +"';deviceside=true";

                    String[][] urlData = XmlFunctions.getUserFromXml(xmlUrl);
                }
            });
            login.setFont(font);
            add(login);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create user interface components");
        }
    }
}
```

On inspecting the email and imei values i get **NULL** and an exception saying **Method "toString" with signature "()Ljava/lang/String;" is not applicable on this object**

It has been a whole day but i'm not able to overcome this problem.

Comment: Which line are you seeing it as null?

Comment: @jprofit: I get null at String e = _email.getText(); the value of **e** is null

Comment: I don't think this is possible. AFAIK getText() always returns a non-null value.

Comment: Is `_email` null or `e`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with accessing non-static outer class fields from an anonymous inner class. Try:

```
String e = Login.this._email.getText();
```

Have a read through [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class).